# C#-When Creating/Deleting database file, consistantly throws readonly exceptions and more

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, sqlite-net

I'm trying to make a preloader C# program for a sqlite database. When I create then read the file, I get exeptions. When I delete and make a ew one, I get exceptions. Can someone please let me know what I'm doing wrong?!

```
string dbPath = @"..\..\..\TidesDatabase\Assets\Database.3db";
        bool exists = File.Exists (dbPath);
        if ( exists )
        {
            File.SetAttributes( dbPath, FileAttributes.Normal );
            File.Delete( dbPath );
            File.Create( dbPath );
            File.SetAttributes( dbPath, FileAttributes.Normal );
        }
        else
        {
            File.Create( dbPath );
            File.SetAttributes( dbPath, FileAttributes.Normal );
        }
        var db = new SQLiteConnection( dbPath );
```

The last line is where the exception is thrown.

Stacktrace:

at SQLite.SQLiteConnection..ctor(String databasePath, SQLiteOpenFlags openFlags, Boolean storeDateTimeAsTicks) in c:\Users\Sgt.Waffles\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\TidesDatabase\Preloader\SqliteNet.cs:line 153
   at SQLite.SQLiteConnection..ctor(String databasePath, Boolean storeDateTimeAsTicks) in c:\Users\Sgt.Waffles\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\TidesDatabase\Preloader\SqliteNet.cs:line 114
   at Preloader.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\Sgt.Waffles\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\TidesDatabase\Preloader\Program.cs:line 40
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

Comment: please post the details of the exception that you are getting

Comment: http://imgur.com/C4qUTHz

Comment: Narayana...the first line of your screenshot contains more text, You can copy and paste that text into your question

Comment: http://imgur.com/dP9L8Ie

Is that the extra you wanted?

Comment: Narayana it seems that the "whole error message" is just "Could not open database file" ? is the path correct ? does it have permission to be accesed by your program ?

Comment: Whether I delete it beforehand or let it delete it it'self, it seems to throw that either way. If I used File.CreateText instead, it throws a ReadOnly exception. I have an explorer window open beside it and I watch as it makes the file. I'm not sure what other permissions or where to set them would be. I went to the parent folder and that's all ~readonly and the Projects folder that everything is in can be accessed at full control by everything.

Comment: File.Create() doesn't just create the file, it returns a FileStream for you to write-to and close. (Usually you would use this in a using statement so that the file is disposed/closed automatically.) Since you don't close the file, it is still open when you try to create the connection. That also wants to open the file, but it can't because the file is already open. @BrianBird is correct: Don't create the file; let the constructor do it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have the right permission to get a file from a path like this.

To get a file you should do:

```
string dbPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal),
    "Database.3db");
```

If you already have a database file, you may put it in Assets folder, then it can be read by using `Assets.Open()`.

Comment: I'm using a preloading exe on my laptop. So the android access part comes next.

Comment: Sorry I probably misunderstood your question. BUT, why you tagged it with Android and MonoDroid? The question itself has nothing to do with Android.

Answer (score 0):

Note: I'm assuming the code in question is 1) running in a console app, not on a mobile OS. 2) using SQLiteNET (an ORM) rather than using SQLite directly.

The problem appears to be that you're creating an empty file and then expecting sqlite to open it as a database file. If a database file doesn't already exist, you need to let sqlite create it. Here's an example:

```
string dbPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "Database.db3");

// If a db file doesn't exist, SQLite-Net will create it
var db = new SQLiteConnection (dbPath);
```

Comment: I am using sqliteNET, I'm new to these so I wasnt sure there was a difference. And the second thing is that I dont see a SQLiteConnection.CreatFile method. I got my SQLiteNET.cs from their website.